# Rate limiting xFTP traffic originating from a Cisco IOS router

Tags: cisco-ios, qos, management

We have some routers on marginal cell links that we need to pull files from using TFTP or FTP. During file transfers connections to the router become so slow as to be unusable.

Is there a way to rate-limit the xFTP traffic originating from a Cisco IOS router?

Would this be a QoS implementation or Control Plane Policing?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use QoS to limit the speed, but that does not actually solve the problem. Things that simply get so slow will still get very slow. It is a problem of back links, and you really cannot make the links any better.

Comment: If the link speed was 200kbps, if I could police the FTP traffic to 100kbps, at least the CLI over SSH would be usable. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the link gets slow due to outside problems ( a real possibility with wireless connections, and possibly due to Internet congetion, too), it will continue to get too slow.